# Error while opening SSIS package in Visual Studio (Incompatible)

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

Quite new to SSIS. To open existing SSIS packages in Visual Studio and I clicked SSIS but it has opened Visual-Studio and not my packages.

In solution explorer showing that SSIS packages(incompatible) and below that "the application not installed",but actually in Extensions windows its showing that installed SSIS. Please help me out resolve the below error (Image).
I tried to modify the package and uninstalled the SSIS tool and installed again. But still same problem

[image]

Comment: SSIS package frameworks seems different, that is why you are facing the issue!

Comment: It just today crashed service,yesterday it works fine.....i changed nothing and my all SSIS projects files present in directory but not loading in visual studio.

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem and I found this menue choice in Visual Studio.  I right clicked the Solution, chose **Resolve Errors** and it resolved my problem.
[image: Resolve Error link]

Comment: Looked everywhere, tried umpteen solutions and who knew answer could be so simple!

Comment: I need that menu option on EVERYTHING

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to install [SQL Server Data Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-ver15) for you to launch the project and test in your local SQL instance. If you're, like me, fairly new to SSIS package, I suggest you follow [this Microsoft official tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/ssis-how-to-create-an-etl-package?view=sql-server-ver15) so that you are familiar with ins and outs of SSIS package.

If you are sure that you have installed all necessary components, please ensure that `VS > Tools > Extensions and Updates > Microsoft Integration Services Projects` is enabled. Once enabled, restart Visual Studio. It might still look the same. Last step is to **right-click on the project and choose "Reload Project"**.

Comment: This works if you've already installed the tools and still have an issue. Thanks for the post.

Answer (score 1):

I already faced the same problem, for some reasons the SSIS extension was disabled.

So to resolve this issue you need to go to :

```
Extensions > Manage Extensions > Installed
```

Make sure that the SSIS extension is enabled then close and reopen you project.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I always ignore and shut down the carking update notification when opening SSIS, until I encountered this error.

I tried googling it and tried "reload project" and "Resolve errors" option, I also uninstalled SSDT and reinstall it, I also disabled and enabled SSIS in "Extensions and Updates" Bar. They all failed.

So I updated SSIS since I'm bored and tired, then I tried "reload project" and "Resolve errors" option again, the magic is everything going fine, like before! It's just my experience, not representative.